# Is there a horizontal scroll widget inside listview

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, android-gallery

I need to make a scrollable row in ListView's item. The row should behave similar to Gallery or ViewPager. It was designed to behave similarly to Facebook gallery.

I was planning to use Gallery but since it has been deprecated I'm not sure if it's a good choice. Although Fragment is recommend to be used to replace Gallery, it's not expected to be put inside a ListView.

Is there other options for available? Or should I implement my own custom view to calculate and handle the view transition? Has anyone try something similar?

Comment: yes..its possible you can create horizontal scroll inside listview

Answer (score 1):

Make the row item a [`HorizontalScrollView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) with a [`LinearLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) inside.
Make the `LinearLayout`'s oriantation `horizontal` and add the things you need inside.

Comment: I found the HorizontalScrollView doesn't support the ability to focus selected item. Or is there to make it behave like that?

Comment: Unfortunately I think it's true. I had to make touchListener to change the background of the selected item (inside the HorizontalScrollView's layoute) and store it's index.